# C# call other class variable but return null (Unity3D)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm using Unity Augmented Reality. Why does my application return a null value if I call a public value of an other class?

These are my classes:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GUIControlScript : MonoBehaviour {

public GUISkin MenuSkin;
public Texture BoxBackground;
public DefaultTrackableEventHandler DTEH;
public string ttx;

void OnGUI(){
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
    GUI.skin = MenuSkin;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, 600), BoxBackground);
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 150, 300, 300));
    try
    {
        GUI.Button(new Rect(0, 0, 500, 500), ttx);
    }
    catch(System.Exception e)
    {

    }
    GUI.EndGroup();
}

void Update()
{
    ttx = DTEH.TrackableText; //This is the problem!
}
```

This is the class where I'm calling the variable

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour,
                                        ITrackableEventHandler
{
#region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
public string TrackableText = "";

#endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

#region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

void Start()
{
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }

    OnTrackingLost();
}

#endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

#region PUBLIC_METHODS

// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
// tracking state changes.
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();

    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}

#endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS

#region PRIVATE_METHODS

private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    // Enable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents) {
        component.enabled = true;
    }
    if (mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName.Equals("farmasi"))
    {
        TrackableText = "farmasi";
    }
    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
}

private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();

    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents) {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}

#endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
```

Comment: Have you tried logging `DTEH`? Is that `null` as well? Can you reacht `Start()` from `DTEH`?

Comment: how to do that..? im new in c# developer..

Comment: Add the following line in your `Update` function of `GUIControlScript`: `Debug.Log(DTEH);`

Comment: Usually, your error message contains what is `null` exactly. Is it `DTEH`? Is is `ttx`? Is it `TrackableText`?

Comment: oh ok.. i try tracing one by one..

Comment: Let me know what the Debug Log gives you. If it returns anything else then `null`, it means it's correctly created and/or called. If it returns `null`, it means the object you try to approach doesn't exist and that's where it goes wrong. Like this, we can narrow down what might possibly be wrong and continue from there.

Comment: sir.. DTEH return NULL value.. how to get other class variable value.?

Comment: Let me know if the answer I posted worked out for you.

Answer (score 1):

Using the discussion in the comments, we managed to narrow it down to see what is `null` exactly. You call `public DefaultTrackableEventHandler DTEH;`, but you never initiate it. Try adding another function in your `GUIControlScript`-class like this:

```
void Start()
{
    DTEH = new DefaultTrackableEventHandler();
}
```

That way, you didn't only give `DTEH` a type, but you initialized it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` extending `MonoBehaviour`, it needs to be attached to a `GameObject` in order for it to initialize. You can do this in one of two ways:

1. In the inspector viewing the `GameObject` that `GUIControlScript` is attached to: add the `Script` manually to the `GameObject` by clicking `Add Component`, choosing `Scripts` (or wherever your scripts are located), and clicking on `DefaultTrackableEventHandler`. In the code, you can then access the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script by calling [GetComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation//ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html?from=MonoBehaviour):

   ```
   public class GUIControlScript : MonoBehaviour {
       private DefaultTrackableEventHandler dteh;

       void Start() {
           dteh = GetComponent<DefaultTrackableEventHandler>();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In the `GUIControlScript` script, call [AddComponent](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation//ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) to programmatically add the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script to the `GameObject`:

   ```
   public class GUIControlScript : MonoBehaviour {
       private DefaultTrackableEventHandler dteh;

       void Start() {
           dteh = gameObject.AddComponent<DefaultTrackableEventHandler>();
       }
   }
   ```

You do not always have to manually add the `Component` to the `GameObject` itself. Typically if you don't have any public variables that you want to change directly in the `Inspector`, then you can just programmatically add the `Component`.